# Google Sheets: How to automatically update month & pull relevant data point for that month

Tags: google-sheets, finance

I'm new to this community, but have seen excellent responses. I'm currently building a financial model in Google Sheets. My goal is to automate the model as much as possible.

Goal: I want to automatically update the month in Google Sheets and add the relevant credit card balance for the given month from a table in the same tab called "credit cards".

Progress: I can update the month by using the "today()" function and converting the date into a text string that only displays the current month (based on date settings). In addition, I was able to add a VLOOKUP formula that pulls the credit card balance from a specific credit card listed in a table below.

Problem: I'm using the following formula to 1) match the current month with month listed in the header of table and 2) pull the relevant credit card balance for that month from a table below.

```
=if(match($F$10,$B$16:$I$16,0),HLOOKUP(B2,$A$15:$J$26,17,FALSE),0)
```

Unfortunately, I'm receiving the same error message: HLOOKUP evaluates to an out of bounds range.

[image: Table]

I want this table to have the update credit card balance for the given month. The next table has the complete credit card balance data where the number should be pulled from.

[image: Table that collects credit card balances]

And I want the formula to pull data from table 2 and add it to table 1 based on given month.

Question: I was wondering if anyone can help me to understand what my mistake is? Again, my goal is to simply match the current month and pull the right credit balance for the given month from a table in the same tab.

I'd truly appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Post few sample data as text table or share a sample google-sheet here. I think you can achieve it with a single function `QUERY()`.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I updated the original question.

Comment: I updated the original post. Unfortunately, Im not able to directly upload images, since I'm new to the community. I hope the additional explanation helps.

Answer (score 0):

A little tricky to grasp without a broader example of your tables and desired output, but I created an example sheet using your screenshots, provided my solutions (which I hope are in-line with what you need), and left explanatory notes in certain cells. As far as determining the error within your attempt, it's hard to tell without access to an example sheet including the methods you attempted.

**Example formula:** `=OFFSET(C1, MATCH(P9, B:B, 0)-1, MATCH(R3, C1:N1, 0)-1)`

> 2 Match functions nested inside an offset function - the Match functions are using inputs to determine how many columns/rows to offset from the starting position (which in this case is C1).

**Example Spreadsheet: [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13R-hP80rjts7txBUkhKI2KeyhS9D1HAvmJ5eE0qG7AI/edit?usp=sharing)**

Feel free to create a copy - hope this helps!